# How to select 0 in JPA CriteriaQuery select clause

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Basically I want to translate the below NamedQuery into JPA Criteria query,

```
SELECT new com.test.vo.ResultVO (0L, 'EmployeeReport', E.FirstName, E.LastName) FROM EmployeeTable E
```

I am using `CriteriaBuilder.construct(QueryResultVO, list of columns to be selected)`.
I understand that to get constant `'EmployeeReport'` I need to use `criteriaBuilder.literal('EmployeeReport')`.

But the issue is how can I get the `0` (Long) for the first column value of the select clause?

as I use the construct method, it expects each column to be a extension of `javax.persistence.criteria.Selection`.

Answer (score 4):

[CriteriaBuilder.literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#literal%28T%29) serves also this purpose. Expression for long literal 0 can be constructed as follows:

```
Expression<Long> longLiteral0 = cb.literal(0L);
```